# Want to move all mails from spam folder to inbox with imaplib python in gmail using python

Tags: python, imaplib

I'm trying to move all mails present in gmail's spam folder to inbox using imaplib. But as a I'm facing issue like below.

> "apply_lbl_msg = obj.uid('COPY', mail_ids, "todays")
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'uid'
> Mail IDs : ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35']"

I'm able to fetch mail IDs but after that I'm not getting what to do I went through various tutorials but still facing the same issue.

Please help me with this friends.Below is my code as far as I tried.If anyone knew the answer means please send me the code.So I can understand....Thanks in advance...

```
import imaplib
obj = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
obj.login('my@gmail.com', 'password')
# obj.select("trials")
resp_code, mail_count = obj.select(mailbox="trials", readonly=True)

############### Retrieve Mail IDs for given Directory #############
obj, mail_ids = obj.search(None, "ALL")

print("Mail IDs : {}\n".format(mail_ids[0].decode().split()))
apply_lbl_msg = obj.uid('COPY', mail_ids, "todays")
if apply_lbl_msg[0] == 'OK':
    mov, data = obj.uid('STORE', mail_ids , '+FLAGS', '(\Deleted)')
    obj.expunge()
```

With above code I tried,But didn't got required result.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to use `imaplib` directly I would recommend using a more user friendly library like [`imap_tools`](https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools):

```
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'pwd', initial_folder='INBOX') as mailbox:

    # MOVE all messages from current folder to INBOX/folder2
    mailbox.move(mailbox.uids(), 'INBOX/folder2')
```

For the specific case of Google Mail I would recommend using their [Python API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) . For example I wrote a small program to filter emails using Python and the Google API, you can find the code on [Github](https://github.com/jan-janssen/pygmailsorter) .

Comment: I already tried this thing earlier...Now also I tried but---Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shiva/PycharmProjects/trials/trilassmtp.py", line 296, in <module>
    with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login("my@gmail.com", "pwd", initial_folder='INBOX') as mailbox:
   "/home/shiva/PycharmProjects/trials/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/imap_tools/utils.py", line 46, in check_command_status
    raise exception(command_result=command_result, expected=expected)
imap_tools.errors.MailboxLoginError: Response status "OK" expected, but "NO" received. Data: [b'authentication failed']

Comment: Just to be sure, did you enable IMAP in the Google Mail settings ? https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229